# Use of with in sentences

Tags: prepositions

> He jumped,with knees that reached to the other players shoulder.

What I try to say is that a basketball player jumped so high that his knees reached to the other player's shoulder. Can I use “with” in this way?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe - it's grammatically correct as far as I can tell, but personally I find it a bit awkward.

*...with knees reaching* seems more natural to me, and I'd interpret the *with* as him having his knees there when he began the jump (cf. *He jumped, with his hand held out* - he held his hand out, then he jumped and kept his hand that way).

Also, a snarky reader will tell you that you don't jump with your knees, you jump with your muscles.

Personally I'd rewrite it to not use *with*:

> He jumped, his knees reaching the other player's shoulder.